# ng2-charts doughnut chart with different data per series

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm trying to create a doughnut chart using ng2-charts that has two series showing something similiar to the array found below.  I'm able to get two series to render as long as the number of items in the data array are equal to the number of labels.  But I'm not able to have a series with the outer ring showing 3 numbers, and the inner ring having 6 numbers and different labels.  Anyone else have experience with it?

```
public summaryDataSets = [

    {

      labels: ['parent1', 'parent2', 'parent3'],

      data: [34, 50, 26]

    },

    {

      labels: ['child1_1', 'child1_2', 'child2_1', 'child2_2', 'child3_1', 'child3_2'],

      data: [14, 20, 30, 20, 10, 16]

    }

  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work with version 2.X. I basically flattened the heirarchical data structure and padded the multiple dataset arrays with zeros. Below is the code that will give you two layer doughnut chart with the second layer showing the split of the first layer section.

```
public summaryTreeChartLabels: Label[] = ['asdf', 'sdgf', 'dfhg', 'asdf_1', 'asdf_2', 'sdgf_1', 'sdgf_2', 'dfgh_1', 'dfgh_2'];

public summaryTreeChartData = [[34, 50, 26, 0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0, 14, 20, 30, 20, 10, 16]];

public summaryTreeChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
```

[image]

Comment: very nice trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can use object notation for this together with a custom tooltip label callback:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [{
          id: 'parent1',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'parent2',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'parent3',
          key: 30
        }],
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
          id: 'child1',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'child2',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'child3',
          key: 30
        }, {
          id: 'child4',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'child5',
          key: 55
        }, {
          id: 'child6',
          key: 30
        }],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (ttItem) => (`${ttItem.raw.id}: ${ttItem.raw.key}`)
        }
      }
    },
    parsing: {
      key: 'key'
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This looks possible, I'll have to figure out how to use it with ng2-charts.  Thank you for the help, I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: MB forgot that part, you will need to install the `next` branch of ng2charts and use at least v3.6 of chart.js to use this

Comment: So I updated my chart.js and ng2-charts packages and totally broke everything.  Definitely some differences.

Comment: When you say "next" branch, which one do you mean? I just installed the 2.4.2 version.

Comment: `ng2-charts@next` which will give you version: `3.0.0-rc.7`

Comment: Oh dear God, what a nightmare of errors. I updated and everything is broken now, like even components that don't use charts.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: So I have the errors down to chartType not a property of canvas. Any idea? I have NgChartModule imported.

Comment: No, verry little experience with the angular wrapper specifics

Comment: Well thank you for what you have done so far.  I'll mark this as answer if I can get it working.